# PHP header(Location: ...): Force URL change in address bar

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

I'm currently working on a mobile site with authentication using PHP sessions with a database.
I have a login page with a form that goes to **server_login.php** on submit. The php file then creates some session data (store in $_SESSION), and redirects the user back to the index page:

```
header("location:../../index.php");
```

The new web page (index.php) loads correctly; however, when the header redirects the page, the URL at the address bar is not changed; it stays at *http://localhost/php/server/server_login.php* instead of *http://localhost/index.php* and thus all my other resources that makes use of relative pathing could not be loaded. It's as if the web page still thinks that it resides at /php/server instead of /.

Strangely, my other use of header("location: ...") at logout.php works and redirects the page successfully with a URL change.

I've made sure that there are no outputs in my *server_login.php* before the header redirect (above it are just mysql calls to check) and I've used ob_start() and ob_end_flush() too.

Are there any methods of forcing the URL on the address bar to change (and thus hopefully fix the relative path problem)? Or am I doing something wrong?

P/S: I am using jQuery Mobile.

EDIT: Here's my code for the redirection that doesn't change the URL:

```
// some other stuff not shown


$sql = "SELECT * FROM $user_table WHERE email = '$myemail' AND password = '$mypassword'";
$login_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

$count = mysql_num_rows($login_result);

if ($count == 1) {

    // Successfully verified login information

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {
        $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = 1;
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $myemail;
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
    }

    // Register user's name and ID
    if ((!isset($_SESSION['name'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])))  {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login_result);
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    }

    header("Location: http://localhost:8080/meet2eat/index.php");

} else {
    // Not logged in. Redirect back to login page
    header("Location: http://localhost:8080/meet2eat/php/login.php?err=1");

}
```

Comment: can you show the code how you post the data?

Answer (score 93):

Try changing:

```
header("Location : blabla")
                ^
                |
           (whitespace)
```

To

```
header("Location: blabla")
```

Answer (score 47):

Well, if the server sends a correct redirection header, the browser redirects and therefore "changes the url". It might be a browser issue, then.
I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but you should not send a relative url in the location header ("HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. ", http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), and "location" must be capitalized, like:

```
header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');
```

Comment: I see. I've fixed the code (as shown above), but I'm still getting the same URL error. :/ I've changed to HTTP Authentication as I realised that's part of my assignment requirement, but I still am intrigued by this weird 'bug'.

Comment: Note the kind of 'catch-all' that is usual in WP's root .htacces: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
Check (i.e. by means of logging) if you get TWO passes after the redirect, your intentional redirect (re-caught by index.php) and another subsequent one that then gets it wrong... implementing an add_filter('[pre_]option_siteurl|home'); do quadruple enforce the new place to be might help you...

Comment: As per RFC 2616, HTTP headers are case-insensitive. The Location header does not have to be capitalized.

Answer (score 19):

In your form element add `data-ajax="false"`.  I had the same problem using jquery mobile.

Comment: I always forget this when using jquery mobile! Worked for me ;)

Comment: I got the same issue. This `data-ajax=false` worked in my case.

Answer (score 14):

Do not use any white space. I had the same issue. Then I removed white space like:

```
header("location:index.php"); or header('location:index.php');
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 9):

you may want to put a break; after your location:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location:  '.  $YourArrayName["YourURL"]  );
break;
```

Comment: You can combine the first 2 lines into one:     header('Location:'.$YourArrayName["YourURL"], true, 301);

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with posting a form. What I did was that turning off the data-ajax.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, he is right.  Must have to do with jquery mobile.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403242/php-header-and-jquery-mobile/8403345#8403345

Comment: Had the same issue.  You just need to add data-ajax on the element that doesn't require ajax (e.g., an <a> link) so that jQuery Mobile doesn't interfere with is... even if it's not in a jQuery Mobile block/form.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the page you are redirecting too doesn't have a redirection within that if no session data is found? That could be your problem

Also yes always add whitespace like @Peter O suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Just change home to your liking

```
$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/home';

header('Location: ' . $home_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for you, Why dont you rather use Explode if your url is something like

Url-> website.com/test/blog.php

```
$StringExplo=explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$HeadTo=$StringExplo[0]."/Index.php";
Header("Location: ".$HeadTo);
```

Answer (score 1):

// Register user's name and ID

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['name'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])))  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login_result);
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
}

header("Location: http://localhost:8080/meet2eat/index.php");
```

change to

// Register user's name and ID

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['name'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])))  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login_result);
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
header("Location: http://localhost:8080/meet2eat/index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As "cfphpflex" suggested you can add `break;` after setting the header.  You can also echo something, such as `echo 'test';`.

Answer (score 1):

Add exit at the end of header then it will work

```
header("location:index.php"); or header('location:index.php'); exit;
```

Answer (score -3):

You are suppose to use it like `header(Location:../index.php)` if it in another folder

Answer (score -3):

use

header("Location: index.php"); //this work in my site

read more on [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) at php documentation.

Answer (score -7):

**why  all of this  location url?**

```
http://localhost:8080/meet2eat/index.php
```

you can just use

```
index.php
```

if the  php files are in the same folder and this is better because if you want to host the files
or change the  port you will have no problem reaching this URL.

Comment: The thing is, the `index.php` is not in the same folder.