# PHP header() and jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, header

I would like to use a php header('Location: newpage.php') to redirect.

I got no error, but Jquery mobile seems to fail loading the destination page and the address bar stays with the old address.

Do you have an advice please ?

Thanks!

Comment: if php's header() isn't redirecting, what makes you think jQuery mobile is to blame? Do you have a link to your code?

Comment: ok fixed. My header('') instruction was not in error. The problem came before. Indeed, I tried this header after receiving elements from a FORM with post method submit by the page itself. I put data-ajax="false" into the attribut of the FORM and it fixed this issue. Thanks all

Answer (score 14):

try to add `data-ajax="false"` when you call that page, before redirecting using php `header()`

Comment: It has nothing to do with ajax. The php header location should be called before any html.

Comment: You are right Cymbals but thanks to Wenkhairu I have remember that I used to put data-ajax="false" on all my FORM in jquery mobile site, I had just forgot to put on this one...

Comment: Actually it does, as jQM changes all <a> call to XHR, and then parses the response. This means that it depends on your navigator's behavior. But since then, in 2014 now looks like to be ok everywhere :)

Answer (score 1):

That code sends a 302 redirect header to the user's browser, instructing it to redirect to the provided URL. It should work. Have you checked the syntax? Information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

I do a header('Location: newpage.php') combined with JQuery Mobile all the time and it works no problem.

I suspect you are trying to send the header after loading any html, which will not work.
The php header **must** occur before any output, including html, JQuery Mobile, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Node.js + JQM and the answer wenkhairu gave fixed it.
The problem is that JQM hijacks navigation behavior and use ajax to navigate, if you put `data-ajax=false` as wenkhairu suggested you tell JQM not to hijack navigation for this form and use regular link/submit behavior

Answer (score -1):

Try turning error reporting on:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","1");
```