# Address Bar not changing - PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I am using header('Location:') to redirect the user to another webpage. But, instead of overwriting the previous address on the address bar, the new one gets appended to the one already present. For example:

The address bar currently holds:

`localhost/v2/admin`

and there is `header('Location:'.DIRADMIN.'login.php');`

where DIRADMIN is a constant defined as

```
define(DIRADMIN,'localhost/v2/admin/');
```

Then, after the redirect, the new address bar would be

```
localhost/v2/admin/localhost/v2/admin/login.php
```

I thought it was because of the server, I am using. I was using Uniform Server Zero. But then I installed WAMP and the problem continues.

I am still a noob, I have no idea what is causing this and if the problem is because of mod_rewrite, then on both servers the module was active. I already checked some of the problems like 
[redirect-PHP header(Location:..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467330/php-headerlocation-force-url-change-in-address-bar)

among others. I even did a google search for this but to no end.
How can I solve this problem?

```
header_remove();
```

will not work as the first address was typed in manually and not set by `header();`

Comment: Try `header('Location:'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/login.php');`

Comment: Please consider setting the `Location` header with a status code (301 -> permanent, 302 temp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

```
define('DIRADMIN','localhost/v2/admin/);
```

As

```
define('DIRADMIN','http://localhost/v2/admin/');
```

Comment: Firstly, it should be `define("DIRADMIN"...` not `define(DIRADMIN...`. The latter method of using assumed strings is not recommended and PHP will issue notices about it (depending on level of error reporting selected).

Comment: Secondly, this is hard wiring your code to the `http` protocol. If you change to `https` at some point in the future you'll need to update all these instances. Either get the current protocol, or use protocol-relative URLS, e.g. `define("DIRADMIN", '//localhost/v2/admin/');`

Answer (score 7):

Without the http prefix, browser is trying to find the path relative to your current one

Add "http://" as so

```
header('Location: '.DIRADMIN.'login.php');
```

If you want URL to be relative to your domain root path, you can just add '/'

```
header('Location: /'.DIRADMIN.'login.php');
```

**You should always try to use a relative path** - That way, if you change your domain, your code still works.

Comment: It worked only for one redirect. The other one still has the same problem.

Comment: @rathorsunpreet Please explain what do you mean by other redirect

Comment: @rathorsunpreet Which of the two examples are you using?

Comment: The other redirect was     
    header('Location:'.DIRADMIN.'?logout');  

It was still not working with your workaround. I then tried, what PHP Worm... wrote and all redirects worked.