# PHP and HTML how can i load in a new file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a login page in PHP where the user inputs their details and they are then posted to another PHP file that then checks the username entered by the user and sees if it registered in the MySQL accounts table, if so it then checks the password and if it's a match I want it to open up the profile page and if not, I want it to return to the login page. How can I get the PHP code to load in a new html/php file to be displayed on the screen. Heres my PHP code so far:

```
<html>

<?php
include_once "mysql_connect.php";

$usersName = $_POST['usersname'];
$passWord = $_POST['passsword'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

$username = "";
$password = "";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    $currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=$i");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
        $username = $row[0];
        $password = $row[1];
    }
    if (($username === $usersName) && ($password === $passWord)) {
        echo "We got you";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "nothing";
    }
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Redirect to login page or profile page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467330/php-headerlocation-force-url-change-in-address-bar

Comment: Why are you running your query across every DB row then comparing in PHP for a match? `$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM allaccounts where username = ?");` You should update your driver so you can use parameterized queries as well; and passwords should be hashed.

Comment: As an aside, there are two _critical_ problems with the code as written. The first is that mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5 and removed in PHP 7; it's highly recommended that you use PDO ([quick tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)). Secondly, you seem to be comparing the password in the database to the input password. It looks like you're storing the password in plaintext in the password, and that is absolutely bad security practice. Instead, use the [password_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash) function and its related methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use header() function. This will redirect to the page specified.

```
if (($username === $usersName) && ($password === $passWord)) {
           header("Location: profile.php");
    } else {
           header("Location: fail.php");
    }
```

Also - get rid of `<html>` at the top. It is of no use and means headers are already sent.

Comment: Don't forget to `exit` or the (unnecessary) loop will keep going.

Comment: That is the correct function, but you'll actually get an error in the above code (hint: had anything already been output to the page?)

Comment: In any other example, yes! but as we redirect the page at this point - it acts as exit. @chris85

Comment: @ChrisForrence, how? besides from the fact i used example file names of course.

Comment: Ah I see - headers. He has <html> at the top for no necessary reason. Will update my answer to note this.

Comment: Well spotted @ChrisForrence!

Comment: The page continues to execute, the header is thrown to the browser though.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php Additionally see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747791/why-i-have-to-call-exit-after-redirection-through-headerlocation-in-php

Comment: Ah I see. Never would have thought. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax` call to do the magic. The ajax call can be made using an inline or external script.

This helps you to display the error message in the same window/page by reducing the complexity of loading another page.

It looks something like this...

```
            // add the code inside a function which should be 
            // invoked on submitting the login details

              $.ajax({

                    type    : "POST",
                    url     : "your_login_check.php",
                    data    : anyVariable,
                    dataType: "HTML",

                    success : function(data){


                        if( data === "We got you"){

                           // Display an error message in a div or simply an alert
                        }

                        else if( data === "nothing"){
                           // Redirect to a specific page

                           window.location = "//Your_another_page.php//";
                        }
              )};
```