# Redirect to another page if a page is not accessed PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect

I want to redirect the user to homepage if he tries to access the "example.com/site" without variable "example.com/site?website=" but if the variable is passed then it should show the desired page.
Note: i am getting the "website" variable on another page from a url.

Comment: use`if(empty($_GET['website']) ||($_GET['website'] == $row['site_title']) ) {` instead of  `if(empty($_GET['website'])) {`  as per your condition

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: In case the redirect itself is not working, please take a look here, and make sure you have proper spaces in header(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467330/php-headerlocation-force-url-change-in-address-bar

Comment: problem is i don't want the user to directly access the example.com/site page without variable "website".

Comment: @u_mulder the problem is i don't want user to access the page "example.com/site" directly without variable like this "example.com/site?website=sdffsd" ...Help?

Comment: You show us code. Is it working? Or is it not? What is the problem with the code you showed?

Comment: its not working .. the page is still accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['website'])) { 
    if($_GET['website'] !== $row['site_title']) {
        header('Location:websites');
      }
} else {
   header('Location:index');
}
```

Above will work, if website is set and your condition satisfy it will redirect to websites else it will always redirect to index page

I hope it will help.

Comment: Forget the code. I don't want the user to access page "example.com/site" directly.

Comment: then use the session concept to allow or not allow based on logged in user or may be role assigned to them.