# HTML/PHP URL Shortener redirecting by ID after / in URL

Tags: php, html, redirect, url-shortener

I'm currently trying to program a URL shortener, but now I have the problem that I do not know how to program the forwarding.

I've made it so far that you can shorten a URL,
e.g. you want to truncate the URL of YouTube, then create an entry in a database that "links" the YouTube URL to a randomly generated ID, say this ID is illustrative `'dzUejsg'`
Now I want to be redirected to the linked URL when entering `sampleurl.com/dzUejsg`, just I do not know exactly how to do that ...

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance for all your answers! 
(Sorry for bad English, I'm german.)

~ JustMarvin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP header(Location: ...): Force URL change in address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467330/php-headerlocation-force-url-change-in-address-bar)

Comment: Enter a custom field instead of an ID. As an example of a self-link. Search for the parameter from the url in the self link column. And redirect according to the result found.

Comment: but isn't it then sampleurl.com/redirect?link=jeuZwnO for example?

Answer (score 0):

If the ID stored in the database is extracted from the URL (ex. https://youtube.com/watch?q=123 and the ID is 123) then you could use the `header("Location: $url")` function.

For example:

```
$url = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=".$id; // Where id is the id from the database.
header("Location: $url");
```

TL;DR Use the `header("Location: <location>");` function

Comment: No, I mean you shorten a link (which can also be a google/reddit/stackoverflow/etc. link) and this link gets an ID generated and stored together in a database

And I want it, that you can enter

sampleurl.com/ID to redirect to the "connected" site.

Like for example bit.ly